# strftime returns incorrect day of the week on iOS

Tags: c++, ctime

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
    tm _tm;
    strptime("2017-04-17", "%Y-%m-%d", &_tm);

    char buf[16];
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%A", &_tm);

    cout << buf << endl;
}
```

On [Ideone](http://ideone.com/7fvom5), it correctly outputs "Monday" (today's day of the week). When I compile and run the same code on iOS, it returns "Sunday". What gives?!

**Edit:** For all those people who can't understand how this is also a C question, here's the C code. The question still stands:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    struct tm _tm;
    strptime("2017-04-17", "%Y-%m-%d", &_tm);

    char buf[16];
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%A", &_tm);

    printf(buf);
}
```

Comment: From man7.org, "The environment variables TZ and LC_TIME are used."  You might want to check both values on each system when you run your program.

Comment: @WeatherVane I believe this is a valid C question as well. Please don't remove the tag.

Comment: @Olaf Do you really need me to reformat this to C just to show that it's a valid C question as well?

Comment: @aardvarkk ... yes? In its current form there is nothing related to C in the question.

Comment: Does anything change if you do `tm _tm = {};`?

Comment: @melpomene Yeah, I tried that since posting the question. Although it made `asctime` look nicer (the hour and minute values were garbage before), the day of the week still shows Sunday. I will create a "C" version of the question for the pedants.

Comment: @aardvarkk you might as well tag any language that overlaps.

Comment: @WeatherVane OK -- any suggestions?

Comment: @yellowantphil I'm not sure what you're referring to? `printf`?

Comment: I cannot compile the C code because my compiler does not know `strptime`.

Comment: @WeatherVane [Ideone has no trouble with it?](http://ideone.com/Eupcoy)

Comment: This is not C code. There is no "ctime" library and the syntax is invalid. There is no actual use in asking about both questions. Why not just use the original language of the library?

Comment: And `strptime` is not a standard function. ideone certainly is not an autoritative reference.

Comment: @Olaf I added a C version. Yes, the syntax differs slightly. I had to add the word `struct` in front of `tm`. `ctime` -> `time.h`. I could have included `time.h` in the so-called C++ example and it would have worked the same way. In fact I could just compile the entire C example as C++ and call it C++. I feel both C and C++ are relevant tags.

Comment: @yellowantphil: **I** know, you know. Yet that was not the point.

Comment: Best to initialize all members of `tm` first  `tm _tm = {0};`

Comment: @chux Yep -- that was half of the problem. On its own, that didn't actually make `strptime` return the correct value for `wday`. For some reason `wday` seems to be set by taking into account the local timezone? Which was very confusing, especially because `strptime` didn't set any timezone values! But by zero-initializing `_tm` *and* by calling `mktime` on it after its return from `strptime`, it had the correct `wday` value set.

Comment: "didn't actually make strptime return the correct value for wday" --> what day did it return?  one day off?  Try tomorrow, `strptime("2017-04-18", "%Y-%m-%d", &_tm);`  I think after zeroing, the `__TM_GMTOFF` member of `tm` needs to match your local.  The point being that many members of `tm` may contribute to DOW  best to set them as desired, although i would have expected zero in all other fields to be the best approach.  Suggest you post the answer.

Comment: @chux Yeah -- it was one day off. I did adjust to "tomorrow" and it was one day off again. I'll post an answer.

Comment: You should check the return value of `strptime`, it may fail and leave garbage in `_tm`

Comment: @M.M The return value was an empty string, which I believe indicates that it completed successfully. But yes, in general it would be good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems leading to the behaviour in the question.

1. `strptime` seems to unexpectedly take local timezone into effect when parsing a date (but only for setting the day of the week!). It seems like when it parses "2017-04-17", at least for the day of the week, it's treating it as something like midnight UTC -- meaning in a negative UTC offset the day of the week at that "time" is one day earlier.

   Basically `strptime` was always giving me `tm_wday` of one less than the correct value. It would return `0` (Sunday) for `tm_wday` when parsing "2017-04-17" (a Monday) and `1` (Monday) for "2017-04-18" (a Tuesday).

   What's very strange is that it wouldn't fill in other timezone data like `tm_isdst` or `tm_gmtoff`. It would leave those unchanged -- just choose a bad value for `tm_wday`.

   I was able to fix this by calling `mktime` on the generated `tm` struct returned from `strptime`. I didn't use the `time_t` returned from `mktime`, but the act of calling `mktime` on the `tm` struct properly set the value of `tm_wday`, *in addition to* correctly setting values for `tm_isdst`, `tm_gmtoff`, and so on.
2. I hadn't zero-initialized the `tm` struct. This only really came into play once I started calling `mktime`. Without proper initialization, `mktime` mangles the date because of garbage values for `tm_gmtoff`. After the proper initialization, calling `mktime` gave a well-formed date with the correct `tm_wday` set.

So a working example would be something like this:

```
tm _tm = {};
strptime("2017-04-17", "%Y-%m-%d", &_tm); // Incorrect tm_wday after this call
mktime(&_tm); // Correct tm_wday after this call

char buf[16];
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%A", &_tm);
```

Answer (score 1):

`strptime()` only updates the fields in the provided `struct tm` that are specified in the format string. The other fields are left alone (and in your case are left uninitialized).

Comment: In this case, `tm_wday` is actually set to 0. I have tried manually setting it to 1, but `strptime` resets it to 0 (Sunday, instead of Monday). So I don't believe this is the problem, although it's obviously best practice for me to have initialized the structure to zero. That doesn't fix the issue, though.

Comment: I think @yellowantphil could be right? It's a timezone issue, perhaps. The date I provide is interpreted as a *time* (probably in UTC). Because I'm my UTC offset is negative, it then calculates the weekday as being the day before? That's my running theory here...

Comment: I  believe it may be related to `tm_isdst` (which is timezone related).

Comment: I am not so sure of this answer - I'll let it sit for a while before deleting it, but I imagine someone will come up with a better answer.

Comment: It's pretty close. I've almost got a solution working locally here. I'll let you know when it's done and you can add my stuff to your answer and we'll make it official.

Comment: OK -- I think I've got it working now. Here's the summary. The `tm` structure was not zero-initialized. `strptime` doesn't care about that, but it sets values strangely. It doesn't set `gmtoff` or `isdst` for GMT offset or DST values, but it *does* set `wday` (albeit to an incorrect value). It looks like it treats the string as a time in UTC, but then sets the weekday based on the local timezone. What I did was to call `mktime` right after parsing the time. This properly sets `gmtoff`, `isdst`, and `wday` to values in the local timezone. Formatting was fine after that.

Comment: Oh, and `mktime` does require the zero-initialized values, otherwise it converts the date to a really wonky value! So basically I had to zero initialize *and* call `mktime` on the value returned from `strptime` to convert it to a local timezone value in order to retrieve the correct `wday` value.

Comment: The [POSIX strptime documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) recommend setting `tm_is_dst = -1;` before calling `mktime`, but its example does not otherwise zero-initialize the struct. (Not sure if bug?)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but perhaps a solution:

If you can work in C++11 or later, [Howard Hinnant's `<chrono>`-based, free, open-source, header-only date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) can get you the same answer on both platforms.

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    istringstream in{"2017-04-17"};
    date::year_month_day ymd;
    in >> parse("%Y-%m-%d", ymd);
    cout << format("%A\n", ymd);
}
```

Portably outputs:

```
Monday
```

This library interprets the parsing and formatting as implicitly in UTC, with no shenanigans with timezones or your computer's current local time zone.  If you need that functionality, it exist in a [separate library built on top of this one](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html).

`"%F"` also works as shorthand for `"%Y-%m-%d"`, as an extension to the POSIX `strptime` spec.

```
in >> parse("%F", ymd);
```

This is a very full-featured datetime library that can handle calendrical features as coarse as a year, and timestamps with as much precision as nanoseconds.  It's all built on the C++ `<chrono>` library, and so is completely type-safe.  Subsequently it is much easier to use than the C/POSIX API, detecting many logic errors at compile-time.